# What's the etymology of "rack focus"?

Tags: etymology

Rack focus [is a](https://www.studiobinder.com/blog/rack-focus-shot-camera-movement-angles/#:%7E:text=A%20rack%20focus%20is%20the,or%20large%20changes%20of%20focus.):

> filmmaking technique of changing the focus of the lens during a continuous shot. When a shot “racks,” it moves the focal plane from one object in the frame to another.

I don't see why one uses the term "rack" in this expression.  What's the etymology of "rack focus"?

---

Example of rack focus:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

A rack is like straight gear - you can see a good animation on the wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack_and_pinion

A camera which has its lens mounted on a suitable rack allows the focus to be changed easily during a shot, by turning a knob (attached to the pinion).

Nowadays other technology can be used to get the same effect, but the name survives.

Comment: Thank you. It's unclear to me though, how the term went from *"normal mechanism for adjusting focus"* to *"specific technique of adjusting focus on the fly"*? Does it mean at one point, there were other types of mechanism, that did not allow to do that?

Comment: Other types of focusing mechanism have been used, for example a twist ring mechanism is common in still cameras. However I expect the verb "rack" did not generally have this meaning until a word was needed for the new technique. Note also that according to https://videocide.com/glossary/racking-focus/ an assistant to the cameraman actually did the racking.

Comment: This question was asked on the French forum, how to translate the phrase; Also, I answered the question about the origin of the phrase. Here is my link for answering it: https://2guysphoto.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/prentis-drews-vintage-film-camera-collection/ I also, said it comes from rack and pinion,

Comment: @Peter I suspect the verb may have also been used in the same sense around rack railways

Answer (score 2):

Here for example is a [macrophotography rack mechanism](https://www.speedgraphic.co.uk/focusing_racks/leofoto_mp150_macro_focusing_rail/29827_p.html) that moves the entire camera by a few cm to focus on small close things.

This could be done with movie cameras as well, moving the camera (and operator), but changing the focus in the lens is an easier way of achieving a similar effect. This is what's used in the example (you can tell because the walls don't move in the frame) and in fact in many examples you can find.

In some cameras, especially old ones*, changing the focus of the lens could also be done using a rack mechanism. Rather than moving the whole camera, only the lens (or some [elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_lens_design#Lens_elements) of the lens) is moved.

* <sub>picture the sort with the lens covered by a bellows instead of a tube</sub>